# AD on-premise migration to Azure AD (On-Prem to be retired)

Tags: active-directory, migration, entra-id

I have the following setup: Exchange 2013 on-premise with 10 users AD on-premise

We have Office 365 premium licenses for each person in the company and have an Azure account etc.

I have been tasked with migrating the users to Office365 and also migrating AD

The Exchange Online licenses are not yet active, so currently, there are no user mailboxes on Office365.

We want Azure AD to replace our on-premise AD as at some point, the AD and Exchange servers (on-premise) will be decommissioned.

What path would be the best for me to take to do the migration?

I have read various pages on docs.microsoft.com about AD sync and AD Connect but am not sure whether or not this is the right way to go. the docs all seem to be geared towards companies needing a hybrid setup and we don't want that.

Tips and advice will be gratefully welcomed.

Best regards,

Neil.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking actually a lot in a few lines, because there are many variables that can influence the actual setup. This is how we usually do this but make sure you understand the steps thoroughly.

For only 10 users, I am not sure if I would setup AD Connect. It's free and easy to setup so you can still do it, but creating 10 users in Office 365 is not too hard.
If you don't setup AD Connect, you need to export and import all mailboxes manually so keep that in mind.

I think I would setup AD Connect and bring your users to Office 365. It's a hybrid setup but you can just break it down very easily afterwards.
Second step is making Exchange Online hybrid (you need at least Exchange 2010 latest SP), migrate your users to Office 365 (assuming you have setup autodiscover, outlook anywhere etc. Check the docs carefully.
If you have all the prerequisites, this is the most easy way to migrate.

Keep in mind that as long as you have AD Connect, you need a On prem Exchange console for managing your attributes. That's the only supported way by Microsoft.
Also, decommission your onprem AD only, if you have no more services that needs it, like a file server.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Hi Erjen.
Thank you for the info. I will start looking into that next week. We have a  window of low use over the week between Christmas and New Year, which is when I will be doing the shift (I hope!)
Have a good weekend,
Neil.

Comment: Good time to make the shift. Have a good weekend.